How to deal with replicates and z-scores?
How would you deal with replicates if you want to calculate z-scores?
My ultimate goal is to make a heat map of gene expression. To do so I have to calculate z-scores.
The analysis consisted of some gene expression data for 6 genes in 6 conditions.
However, each gene that we used for the analysis, was analyzed 5 times (thus we have 5 replicates for each gene).
Moreover, I have 2 NA values in gene 5 replicate 3, and replicate 5 is in every case an outlier.
How would you approach this? My first question as an ignorant biologist is: should I do the mean (or median because of the outlier) of my data, and then calculate the z-score? but if so, in the formula (x-mean)/sd, what should x be?
I also tried to calculate the z-score for each replicate of each gene and then do the mean, but the result looks very weird.
